# how to produce smaller files of photos of documents

Tags: camera

I'm on a Huawei P30 Lite.  The camera resolutions are 15, 18, and 24 megapixel. I don't take a lot of photos but I've noticed a typical photo of a document of text is often more than 4 megabytes.  This is way more than I need.  Problem 1... This takes longer than I would like to upload via Bluetooth.  Problem 2.... I have to run an application on my computer to make the files smaller.  I am trying to avoid these 2 problems.

Skype on the same phone takes photos of text documents with the resulting file often less than 100 kilobytes.  This is surprising because I thought Skype would use the camera application on the phone.  I Skype the photo to my alternate Skype account and Skype uses WiFi which is much faster than Bluetooth.

How can I set up my phone to take photos that result in a smaller file size.  You can assume my needs are grey scale and text only.

Comment: This depends on whether you're okay with installing 3rd-party camera apps or not since the built-in camera app may not have enough settings to reduce the file size.